# Edit text with icons on both sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have to do an Edit Text with two Font Awesome Icons inside it: 
[image]

My problem is to add these icons (Left and Right), how can I do it?

Here is my custom_search.xml drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/grayLighter" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `drawableLeft` and `drawabelRight` in your xml like follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_drawables_added"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"" />
```

There are more options, like `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`. You can try them anyway you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply DroidDev, but my icons are inside a .otf file. I created a custom view <icon> which I can easily create these icons inside and xml, could you show how to apply this? I'm kinda new on android

Comment: I am sorry @Kayan but, I have only seen .otf files used for text styling. What I am not able to understand is, how your icons are inside .otf file.

Comment: Yeah, the designers sent all Font Awesome Icons inside an otf file, So I've done a Custom Text View, on its constructor I set the TypeFace... So I guess it would be some hack to insert on `android:drawableRight="my custom text view with typeface"`

Comment: Actually the thing with `drawable` is that it will only take a drawable object i.e. a file from drawable folder in your app. Unless you don't extend EditText class into your custom class and edit that property of Edittext, but that's a pretty long and tedious way. You can instead just ask your designers to provide these icons separately as .png files.

Comment: You need to have exact icon sizes for this too work, on future devices it is guaranteed to break.

Comment: Hi @iLoveUnicorns. Thanks for the input, though this is an old answer, please feel free to edit the answer and add your warning to it. Also, please don't forget to give any references that you have, in regard to the warning, because we need to justify everything :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do :

```
 <EditText 

    android:drawableLeft="your drawable"
    android:drawableRight="your drawable"
    />
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I posted?

Comment: You need to have exact icon sizes for this too work, on future devices it is guaranteed to break.