# How to create border at bottom only?

Tags: android, button

I am trying create one app and in my app I am trying to create border at bottom in button,but when I run application it shows border at top only,can anybody tell how to achieve this..following is my xml of UI?.........

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.button_pressed_effect_example.MainActivity" >

 <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_black_orange"
   android:drawableBottom="@drawable/liti"

    />
<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Two"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_black_orange"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

liti.xml

```
      <layer-list /android">
         <item   android:left="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
         <shape android:shape="line">

        <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
        </item>
        </layer-list>
```

custom_btn_black_orange.xml

```
 <selector >

  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#5B0B0E"
             android:endColor="#5B0B0E"  />           
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

         <solid  android:color="#731013"/>      
     </shape>
 </item> 
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#5B0B0E"
             android:endColor="#5B0B0E" />           
     </shape>
 </item>
 </selector>
```

custom_btn_black_orangepressed.xml

```
    <selector>

   <item android:state_pressed="false" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#5B0B0E"
             android:endColor="#5B0B0E"  />           
     </shape>

 </item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

         <solid  android:color="#731013"/>      
     </shape>
 </item> 
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

         <gradient
             android:angle="-90"  
             android:startColor="#5B0B0E"
             android:endColor="#5B0B0E" />           
     </shape>
 </item>
 </selector>
```

Myjava.java

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_black_orangepressed);
            btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_black_orange);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_black_orangepressed);
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_black_orange);
        }
    });
```

Comment: [drawableBottom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28235653/2389078) might do

Comment: I already use check question

Comment: are you sure that your custom shape is not interfering with the drawable added at bottom?

Comment: no I am not sure..sorry..

Comment: you can check that by removing the custom shape and only applying drawable bottom. For more clarity, you can also try `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` for button with `drawableBottom`

Comment: yes i tried but still its showing at top only..

Comment: @DroidDev can you check it?

Comment: just check declaration of your second Button: You are using  `android:background="@drawable/custom_one"`
I guess it should be `android:background="@drawable/customone"` bcoz you only shown code of customone xml

Comment: no its not mistake,,,,,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is different or you are unable to explain it, however I got it

1. Crete two files in drawable, bottom_selected and bottom_unselected

Bottom_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#001EFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Bottom_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#001EFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Now your Buttons

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_selected"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_unselected"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_unselected"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Final View

[image]

Comment: Works Perfect as needed!

Answer (score 2):

**Code** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Minus (-) how much dp you gave in the stroke width from left right top-->
    <item android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp" android:top="-10dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
            <!--This is the main background -->
            <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Preview** -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#eecc68" />
</shape>
```